# Sql query on clicked button

Tags: php, html, button

I would like to ask how can I call Sql query when HTML button is pressed. I watched a couple tutorials, but never got it to work correct, thats why I would like to ask here.

So..I have a list of items displayed, and the list is generated from database. Here is how the code looks like:

```
<table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="5" style="background-color:#FFC" >
<td>Id</td>
<td>Text</td>
<td>Solved?</td>
<td></td>
<?php
while( $array = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryRun) ) {
    ?><tr>
    <td><?php echo $id = $array['id'].'<br />';?></td>
    <td><?php echo $text = $array['text'].'<br />';?></td>
    <td><?php echo $reseno = $array['solved'].'<br />';?></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="Solve it" /></td>
    </tr><?php
}?>
</table>
```

Now each item that is generated inside this loops has a button "Solved" at the end of the table, and I want to make it so when user click on that button, do a Sql query which changes a value of solved from 0 (false) to 1 (true).

Answer (score 0):

You need ajax. write button onclick and make ajax call.

Comment: Yes, so far I was able to use "alert" with that method, but how can I call Sql query?

Comment: Javascript ajax - http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_example.asp
Jquery ajax- http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
you can try out example for the button click as you wanted for the javascript ajax link

Answer (score 0):

I've not tested this, but it should work.

Basically I've applied a class to anything to easily select stuff in jQuery:

```
<?php while ($array = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryRun)) { ?>
<tr class="row">
    <td class="cell_id">
        <?php echo $array['id']; ?>
    </td>
    <td class="cell_text">
        <?php echo $array['text']; ?>
    </td>
    <td class="cell_solved">
        <?php echo $array['solved']; ?>
    </td>
    <td class="cell_solve_it">
        <input class="button_solve_it" type="button" value="Solve it" />
    </td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Then I've created this short jQuery script:

```
$('.row').each(function(){
    $('.button_solve_it', this).click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.post(
            'solve_query.php',
            {
                id: $('.cell_id', this).html(),
                text: $('.cell_text', this).html()
            },
            function (data) {
                $('.cell_solved', this).html('1');
            }
        );
    });
});
```

In short:
when you click a `.button_solve_it` button, you make an AJAX request to `solve_query.php`, where you perform your SQL query.
Then, it sets the content of the row in `Solved?` column to `1` (or to `true` or whatever you want).